# Flash Game won't play online after loading

Tags: flash, web

I uploaded my game to my website.  The page works perfectly fine when I open up the html file in my browser, but when I upload it onto my website it will not play. I found when I change the parameter: "loop" to off, I can right-click and select "play" to make my game run, but there seems to be no way to make it play automatically and not loop.

Might it have something to do with how my preloader is on frame 1 and the game frame 2?

Here is some code:

```
<div id="flashContent">
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="goofspiel" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="goofspiel.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->    
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data        ="goofspiel.swf" width="550" height="400">
                    <param name="movie" value="goofspiel.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess"     value="sameDomain"     />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images     /shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
                </object>
</div>
```

Still, it works perfectly fine offline, I just don't understand why it doesn't work online.

Thankyou.

Comment: We can't be just guessing things out of the blue, can we? Share info about the game, not just the problem...

Comment: I added some code. Hope it helps. It is a simple card game in flash.

Comment: Can we it on your website, so we can see the issue and i totally agree with  @loxxy

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here. But I got my movie to start playing. If you wait like 2-3 minutes once it's all loaded it will play. I also took off classid thingy. Maybe for your game   you should try to put a loading screen. Thats my best guess. cheers